# Rails Validate Uniqueness Isn't Working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Model Code (Attempting to require uniqueness for `embed_code`)

https://gist.github.com/1427851:

```
class Link < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :embed_code, 
            :format => {:with => /^<object type|^<embed src|^<object width|^<iframe src|^<object height|^<iframe width|^<embed id|^<embed width|^<object data|^<div|^<object id/i, :message => "Invalid Input"}, 
            :uniqueness => true
  attr_accessible :title, :embed_code, :score
  after_initialize :calculate_score, :favs_count
  attr_accessor :score, :fav_count
  validates :title, :length => { :in => 4..45, :message => "Must be between 4 & 45 characters"} 


  before_save :resize

  has_many   :favorites
  has_many   :favorited, :through => :favorites, :source => :user
  belongs_to :user
```

I've tried `validates_uniqueness_of :embed_code` and disabling (commenting out) non-critical components of the model such as `:before_save :resize`

Comment: Is it a case issue?  By default `uniqueness` validations are case sensitive, so `<code>A</code>` and `<code>a</code>` are considered unique.

Comment: I can't imagine it being an issue of case, I'm simply copying and pasting youtube `iframe` code into the form. However I have checked to see if youtube alters any parameters in the embed code for tracking purposes but the code is the same. I've tried several different codes and even disabling parts of my model. I guess that I just haven't looked at my code hard enough.

Comment: I just queried my db to double check.. Identical codes.

Comment: Are you seeing the uniqueness query in your logs? It would be something like "select * from links where embed_code = '#{embed code}'". If you were saving an existing record, it would also include a "id <> #{id}" clause. Looking at what the embed code in the query should guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Are you certain that the whitespace is identical in your duplicates? You might also want to add a unique index to your database just for extra paranoia, you'll want an index on the embed code anyway if you're going to be validating its uniqueness and you don't like table scans (and hey, who likes table scans?). You should also standardize your embed codes before putting them in the database: sort the `<param>`s and attributes, normalize case of the attributes and tags, sort the query parameters in any URLs, ...

Comment: @muistooshort I think you're correct about indexing. I'm testing locally, after about 10 minutes of plugging the same code in, it finally rejects it

Comment: So the database notices the duplicates but `validates` does not?

Comment: It seems that there's a delay before duplicates are sensed, would indexing speed this up?